# CMIS: How to look for all properties of a document type?

Tags: cmis, ecm

I'm trying to find out how to create a cmis query that returns the properties of a specific document. Not the values, just the property name and its type. For example: property "dateCreated" type "String".

Answer (score 1):

You have to get the type definition of the document. It contains the property definitions, which provide the information you are looking for.
If you are using OpenCMIS, DotCMIS, or PortCMIS, you access the property definitions like this: `doc.getType().getPropertyDefinitions()`

See also https://chemistry.apache.org/docs/cmis-samples/samples/types/index.html and https://chemistry.apache.org/java/javadoc/org/apache/chemistry/opencmis/commons/definitions/PropertyDefinition.html